# Fill in a group table with $4$ elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> There is exactly one group $G$ of four elements, say $G = \{e, a, b, c\}$ satisfying the
>   additional property that $xx = e$ for every $x \in G$. Complete the following group table of $G$.
>
> $$
> \begin{array}{c|lcr}
>  & e & a & b & c\\
> \hline
> e & e & a & b & c\\
> a & a &  &  \\
> b & b &  & \\
> c & c &  & 
> \end{array}$$

Every $x$ in $G$ satisfies $xx = e,$ so $aa = e, bb = e, cc = e.$

first row: $ab \neq a$ because it's given that $b \neq e.$ Also, $ab \neq b$ since $a \neq e.$ So, $ab = c.$ Thus, $ac = b.$

second row: $ba \neq a$ since $b \neq e.$ So, $ba = c.$ Then, $bc = a.$

third row: $ca \neq a$ since $c \neq e.$ So, $ca = b$ and $cb = a.$

So,  $$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
 & e & a & b & c\\
\hline
e & e & a & b & c\\
a & a & e & c & b\\
b & b & c & e & a\\
c & c & b & a & e
\end{array}$$

Please, check my work.

Comment: This is correct. You are calculating the Klein 4-group, Google that for further confirmation.

Comment: I wish more questions were like this on MSE. Nice work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Fortunately" there are [only two choices](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_4) for a finite group of order $4$.

One is [$(\mathbb{Z}_4,+)$](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Cyclic_group:Z4#Multiplication_table), which is not unipotent.

The second choice, $(\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2,+)$ or *Klein four-group*, is indeed unipotent and, if you check [this Cayley table](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Klein_four-group#Multiplication_table) of it, you'll have your solution confirmed with no even need of relabelling the elements.

Comment: I am trying to prove these two are the only groups on the set of $4$ elements. There are $3$ $x \neq e$ in Klein four group s.t. $xx = e.$ There's no group with $4$ elements where $4$ or more of its elements($x \neq e$) abide by $xx = e.$ So, we can have maximum $3$ groups with $4$ elements. My strategy is to rule out one of them by contradiction. We can use following theorems to do that: $(1.)$ If the order of $G$ is even, there is at least one $x \neq e \in G$ s.t. $x^2 = e.$ $(2.)$There is exactly one group G of four elements s.t. $\exists x \neq e (x^2 = e)$ and $\exists y(y^2 \neq e).$